# How do I loop through a list in a data frame, select only one element from it. Then remove rows that contains the elements which was not selected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

`places_within_catchment` has a list of place_ids.

Based on the example below, from `places_within_catchment`, if `place_id` 3 has the highest sales, remove rows where `place_id = 2`.

So, going immediately to the third row (since row number 2 has been deleted), remove rows where p`lace_id = 2` and `place_id = 5`.

How can I do this in a Python function?

I have tried:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_df_copy.columns)

for index, row in new_df_copy.iterrows():
    max_avg_sales = 0
    max_id = 0
    
# Find the id with the highest avg_sales within places_within_catchment
for place_id in row['places_within_catchment']:
    if place_id in new_df_copy['id'].values:
        avg_sales = new_df_copy.loc[new_df_copy['id'] == place_id, 'avg_sales'].values[0]
        
        if avg_sales > max_avg_sales:
            max_avg_sales = avg_sales
            max_id = place_id

# Append the row with the maximum avg_sales to the result DataFrame
result_df = pd.concat([result_df, new_df_copy.loc[new_df_copy['id'] == max_id]], ignore_index=True)

# Display the result DataFrame
print(result_df)
```

This is the code to reproduce the table below:

```
# Data for the new DataFrame
data = {
    'place_id': list(range(1, 6)),
    'avg_sales': [500.4, 200.4, 600.25, 200.93, 60.1],
    'places_within_catchment': [[2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1], [1, 3]]
}

# Create the DataFrame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the result
print(new_df)
```

[image]

this is more on the expected output and its logic

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there expected result?

Comment: @AndrejKesely..updated with a picture of the expected output and the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood you right, you can try:

```py
data = {
    "place_id": list(range(1, 6)),
    "avg_sales": [500.4, 200.4, 600.25, 200.93, 60.1],
    "places_within_catchment": [[2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5], [1], [1, 3]],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["places_within_catchment"] = df["places_within_catchment"].apply(set)
df = df.set_index("place_id")

removed = set()
for idx, p in zip(df.index, df.places_within_catchment):
    if idx in removed:
        continue

    to_check = p - removed
    if len(to_check) == 0:
        continue

    removed |= p - {df.loc[df.index.isin(to_check), "avg_sales"].idxmax()}

final_df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(removed)]
print(final_df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   place_id  avg_sales places_within_catchment
0         1     500.40                  {2, 3}
1         3     600.25               {1, 2, 5}
2         4     200.93                     {1}
```

Comment: tq.. it worked.